# How to make lowercase of a uppercase table caption?

Tags: tables, captions

I am using the below code to make uppercase of a table caption. However, I want make the unit (such as mm) as lowercase. How could I change it

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage[tablename=TABLE]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{up}{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}
\captionsetup[table]{
    labelsep=period,
    justification=centering,
    textformat=up,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{This is table with unit mm}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use `\MakeTextLowercase` with the units?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage[tablename=TABLE]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{up}{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}
\captionsetup[table]{
    labelsep=period,
    justification=centering,
    textformat=up,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{This is table with unit \MakeTextLowercase{mm}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You save my life

Answer (score 5):

The unit can also be set by package `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage[tablename=TABLE]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{up}{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}
\captionsetup[table]{
    labelsep=period,
    justification=centering,
    textformat=up,
}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{This is table with unit~\si{\milli\meter}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

But, uppercase for caption titles is not my taste, because it reduces readability and it is unnecessarily "crying".